# Можно ли заполнить навигационное свойство в предварительно сформированом анонимном объекте?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, оптимизация, linq

Есть следующие классы

```
public class Operation
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
}

public class Act
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Number {get;set;}
    public int OperationId {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<ActHistory> History {get;set;}
    public virtual Operation Operation {get;set;}
}

public class ActHistory
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int ActId {get;set;}
    public int ActStateId {get;set;}
}
```

Мне необходимо для каждой операции(`Operation`) получить ***последний акт***(Act) и затем *отфильтровать* операции на основании поля `ActStateId`(находится во внешней таблице `ActHistory`), т.е. получить только те операции у которых последнее состояние последнего акта соответствует условию.

у меня получился следующий запрос:

```
var _operationAct = _context.Set<NewAct>()
    .Include(x => x.History)
    .ToList()
    .Where(x => x.History.Last().ActStateId != (int)DTO.ActState.Archive)
    .OrderBy(x=>x.OperationId)
    .GroupBy(x => x.OperationId)
    .Select(x => new { OperationId = x.Key, Act = x.Last() });
```

Он отрабатывает но для того что бы получить последнее состояние *акта* мне приходится предварительно *материализовать* всю коллекцию актов и истории актов, что мне кажется не оптимальным.

Предпринял попытку переписать данный запрос, и вот что у меня получилось:

```
var operationAct = _context.Set<Operation>()
    .GroupJoin(_context.Set<NewAct>(), o => o.Id, a => a.OperationId, (o, a) => new
    {
        OperationId = o.Id,
        LastActs = a.OrderByDescending(_ => _.Id).FirstOrDefault()
    })
    .OrderBy(x=>x.OperationId)
    .ToList();
```

т.е. для каждой операции я получаю последний акт либо `null` при отсутствии такового
что бы осуществить фильтрацию на основании поля `ActStateId` мне необходимо *заполнить* навигационное свойство `History` у *акта*.

Возможно ли средствами *EF* заполнить навигационное свойство `History` у получившегося анонимного объекта `operationAct`?